# Array becoming null when List.toArray is used

Tags: java, arrays

I'm having an issue where I'm trying to populate an Array with values from a list, then replace the old values with the new ones upon each call of the method. The code below works once, then the next attempt it gives no errors until the new array variable is used , as the array which should have been populated with list data just is full of null values. If anyone has any suggestions much appreciated.

```
Integer[] stockFF2 =new Integer[ordersBFList.size()]; 
Integer[] ordersFF2 =new Integer[stockBFList.size()];
stockFFList.toArray(stockFF2);
ordersFFList.toArray(ordersFF2);
```

Comment: From this code, I can not figure out what you are hoping to happen

Comment: Add doe which produces the exception and post the stack trace and tell us at what line it happens.

Comment: +, it seems like you should switch **sizes**.

Comment: @sparta Thanks! that at solved one issue but the null one is still there though

Comment: `null` speaks for itself. You tripped somewhere in your code. Keep digging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have got the sizes wrong (orderFF2 and stockFF2 are using the sizes of each other's lists). I suspect one of the arrays is populated properly - one with the larger array - while the other allocates and returns a new array with the elements you want keeping the passed in array as it was because it is too short.

Answer (score 1):

The `toArray()` method makes a fresh array and copies the contents of the list into it.

Try

```
Integer[] stockFF2 = stockBFList.toArray(); 
Integer[] ordersFF2 = ordersBFList.toArray();
```

If you want to reuse these arrays (seldom worthwhile), then replace their values with:

```
stockFF2 = stockBFList.toArray(stockFF2); 
ordersFF2 = ordersBFList.toArray(ordersFF2);
```

It's unsafe to ignore the return value. If the source Collections get larger, the return value is another fresh array.

Comment: Actually. toArray works in both modes, either taking an array as an argument, filling it as well as returning it. BUT the input array *must* match the list size, which is the problem in the OP example, where the two lists are swapped.
toArray() without an argument returns an Object array.

Comment: *"It's unsafe to ignore the return value."* - +10